# Printing on a paper at exact positions. Should i use WPF?

Tags: wpf, forms, printing, position

I want to be able to print a form from a win forms application. The restriction though lies in the face that I have to print it on a pre printed form with specific locations for text and I should not overflow the text. Would using WPF be a good idea for that? Or any suggestion on what can be used for precise placement of text on paper to be printed exactly at the same place irrespective of the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FixedDocument is designed for "what you see is what you get" (WYSIWYG) applications where the document layout is defined and controlled by the application for rendering to the highest accuracy of the display or print device.

[FixedDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument.aspx)

I believe this requires WPF.   It is just a .NET class but no viewer for WinForms.